# VB6: destroying redundant GDI handles held by a component

Tags: vb6, activex, gdi

I'm maintaining an old legacy app in VB6. The app uses UI components written by an external vendor, to which we do not have source code (ActiveX controls).

Today I found out that these controls are extremely wasteful in GDI resources. Specifically, I created a form with 4 regular textboxes and then another form with 4 textboxes from this vendor's controls. The vendor's controls had %37 more GDI resourse usage, and specifically, the vendor's form had 15 fonts, while the regular one had 5 or 6 (I think it was 4 for the textboxes, 1 for the form).

Assuming there is nothing I can do to contact the vendor, and assuming I can trace fonts that are not really used by the controls - is there a way in which I can destroy these fonts?

Comment: No - you'll likely crash the components. The vendor created those resources for a specific reason and the controls' code relies on them. If you don't like the resource usage (which is understandable, some vendors ship really bad code), don't use those controls.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I assumed.